# Is there a term and design principle for the auditability/ observability/ traceability of system processes?

Tags: terminology

Is there a term and design principle for the auditability/ observability/ traceability of system processes? For example, I've got a product with a calculation engine at it's core, it's passed a list of criteria and reads a list of transactions - it then returns a list of eligible transactions. It's a bit of a black box, I would like to implement auditability/ observability/ traceability into the process so that the end-user is able to understand how we determined that value. So as an end-user I can see how, why and what steps were taken to get to this result.

Is there a better term to describe this? Is there a design and/ or software principle that documents this?

I've spoken to a few colleagues and we can't agree on a common name, I feel like it should be a pretty standard concept but google would suggest not.

Comment: Are you looking for logging..?

Comment: As a concept it should definitely include logging but it's more than that, logging every step of the process and presenting parts back to the user as an audit trail and step by step breakdown of the calculation, what would you call that thebjorn?

Comment: Transparency and Interpretability has been used, but those are very generic words... We've always used a button named "Explanation" (so "explainability"..?). It might depend on the intended audience as well, e.g. an explanation to a regular end-user is meant to give confidence in the result while a systems-auditor will need enough data to verify the result.